# Working on Php solution for getting data from eCommerce Merchant to Validation page

Tags: php

I think this is a problem we Web Designers are going to run into frequently working with CMS scripts.
and with all the new shopping carts and eCommerce Payment Gateways coming out.

I have a Component with a newer shopping cart running on Joomla that generates a Unique
URL for each order. Need to process it in Authorize.net SIM 
compatible Gateway. (Hosted Payment Page)

I used a 2 Form solution to get the correct information to the Gateway, and payment can be made successfully.

Now I have to get the data back to Validate the payment and update the shopping cart.

I need to move the response code data to a dynamic URL.

The Gateway only posts to a static URL.

They suggested I  have the Gateway post back to a static page that then auto posts to the correct unique generated URL.

They advise that the  static page will pick up the response elements the shopping cart  requires in the database, and then push the information to the second URL that is unique to the Individual transaction.
Also advise redirect be Auto Post or Post.

The Developer kindly wrote a snippet of code that is supposed to pick up the unique identifier for the order, generate the correct URL and to act as the Redirect,

```
 <?php
if($_POST || $_GET) {
    $vik = explode('_', $_REQUEST['x_fp_sequence']);
    $querystring = '';
    foreach($_REQUEST as $k=>$v) {
        $querystring .= '&'.$k.'='.$v;
    }
    header('Location: http://allstoplimo.com/reservations/index.php?option=com_vikrentcar&task=notifypayment&sid='.$vik[0].'&ts='.$vik[1].$querystring);
}
 ?>
```

Which I have tried to combine with static standard static receipt page example provided  by the Gateway:

```
  <?php
 if ($_REQUEST['x_response_code'] == '1') {
   echo "<p>";
   echo "Your order was processed successfully. Here is your receipt.";
   echo "Your order will be shipped in two business days.";
   echo "</p>";
   echo "<pre>";
   echo $_REQUEST["exact_ctr"];
   echo "</pre>";
   if (!empty($_REQUEST["exact_issname"])) {
     echo "<p>";
     echo "Issuer: " .$_REQUEST["exact_issname"] . "<br/>";
     echo "Confirmation Number: " . $_REQUEST["exact_issconf"];
     echo "</p>";
   }
   echo "<p>";
   $track_url = "http://allstoplimo.com/reservations/" . $_REQUEST["x_invoice_num"];
   echo "You can track it at <a href=\"" . $track_url . "\">" .
$track_url . "</a>";
   echo "</p>";
 } elseif ($_REQUEST['x_response_code'] == '2') {
   echo "<p>";
   echo "Your payment failed.";
   echo "Here is your receipt.";
   echo "</p>";
   echo "<pre>";
   echo $_REQUEST["exact_ctr"];
   echo "</pre>";
 } else {
   echo "<p>";
   echo "An error occurred while processing your payment.";
   echo "Please try again later.";
   echo "</p>";
 }
?>
```

The receipt info is posting to the static page but 
Of course it is not redirecting anywhere???

Any suggestions on an alternative?